# Converting a (negative) double value to string using ToString() method

Tags: types, c++-cli, tostring

I am using the `ToString()` method to convert a double precision value to `string`. It works fine for positive numbers, but when the double is a negative value, for example -5, the resultant `string` is `5-`. I could not figure out how to use the format specifier properly.

```
public: void displaynumber(double x) {
    richTextBox1->Text = x.ToString();
}
```

I've tried the format `ToString("D")` from reading MSDN on formatting, which compiled without errors, but I got an exception at run time: "format specifier was invalid".

Comment: What is this `ToString` method? Do you have any documentation for it? What library is it part of? (Are you sure this is C++? I don't see how a `double` could have a member function.)

Comment: Are you using C#?  A lot of code on the MSDN site is in C# (as one of the languages).

Comment: No, I am not using c#. I used C# quite a bit at work, but I am using c++ to teach my kids and stumbled on this a little bit. The ToString() method is part of System ... here is the description below ...

Comment: oops .. running out of time .. this method has about 15 overloads ..virtual System::String ^System::Double::ToString(System::String ^format)... Converts the numeric value of this instance to its equivalent string representation, using the specified format.

Answer (score 0):

The [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) function is in the `<string>` library so you would do

```
#include <string>

public:
    void displaynumber(double x)
    {
        richTextBox1->Text = std::to_string(x);
    }
```

the syntax `x.ToString()` would mean that `ToString` is a method of `x` which is a `double` and has no such method.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but this works for positive or negative value of x, the only problem is for negative value, the string displayed has the negative value at the end of string .. such as "5-" instead of "-5". The string value itself is correct, just wrong placement of the negative symbol.

Comment: I *assure* you if you are using standard C++ then `x.ToString()` will *not* compile for any value of `x`. If you are using some other language or some extension (maybe `C++/CLI`?) then you should mention that.

Comment: I am using visual c++ 2005 express. Yes.. it is CLI.

Answer (score 0):

`x.ToString()` implies that ToString is a method of x which is a data type `double` and should not compile at all. Whereas, `to_string` is a function in the `<string.h>` library.

```
#include <string>

public:
    void displaynumber (double x) {
        richTextBox1 -> Text = std::to_string(x);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If [`Double.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tostring.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) is giving you `5-` instead of `-5`, it's probably because you're computer is set to a culture where the sign comes after the number. (Where are you located in the world? What language is Windows set to?)

If you want `-5`, always, regardless of the culture the program is running in, the easiest way is to specify the culture to use. In this case, I'd leave off the format specifier, and just specify [`CultureInfo::InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) on the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shxtf045.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) that takes just a format provider.

```
richTextBox1->Text = x.ToString(CultureInfo::InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I'm in san diego county. I tried inserting the CultureInfo::InvariantCulture inside the parentheses, but it complained in compilation.

Comment: If it's complaining that it can't find CultureInfo, `using namespace System::Globalization;`. Otherwise, please don't make me guess what the error message was.

Comment: x.ToString() actually works... it returns the correct string ..even when x ia negative ... the problem is in richTexBox1 when it actually displays the text/string on the form, it puts the negative sign after the number. But if I just look in the watch variable the text value of richTextBox1 actually shows the correct string.. even for negative number .. ie when x=-56 the text would be "-56" .. but when it displays on the form .. it becomes 56-

Answer (score 0):

x.ToString() actually works... it returns the correct string ..even when x ia negative ... the problem is in richTexBox1 when it actually displays the text/string on the form, it puts the negative sign after the number. But if I just look in the watch variable the text value of richTextBox1 actually shows the correct string.. even for negative number .. ie when x=-56 the text would be "-56" .. but when it displays on the form .. it becomes 56-.

That is a subject for another debugging or question.
Thanks for all who attempted to help.